# TreeTableModule import from primeng causes error

Tags: angular, primeng, treetable

I'm trying to use TreeTable from primeNG, but when i import it's module i.e. `TreeTableModule` to `app.module.ts` it causes following error:

[image]

I have not used `DropdownModule` but still error shows:

> Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module `DropdownModule`.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { OrganizationChartModule } from 'primeng/organizationchart';
import { TreeTableModule } from 'primeng/treetable';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OrganizationChartModule,
    TreeTableModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [ HttpClientModule ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have no clue why and from where this issue is causing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you Module:
Missing commas

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule
   ,routing <= Missing Comma
   ,FeatureComponentsModule
  ],

imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
   ,routing <=Double Comma
   ,FeatureComponentsModule
  ],
```

Comment: Hi Make sure the modules don't import each other. So, there shouldn't be

In Module A: imports[ModuleB]

In Module B: imports[ModuleA]

Comment: actually i'm importing it to `app.module.ts` and there is no other module created till now.

Comment: can you share your app.module.ts file

Comment: this is a not TreeTableModule problem. I think you're using the dropDown plugin in some component and you do not import DropdownModule in app.module.ts file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200692/discussion-between-upinder-kumar-and-om-prakash).